# What is the best approach to attain multi-tenancy in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant, row-level-security

I'm using django as an API server(using DRF) and admin dashboard with Postgres DB. The problem is I'll have multiple tenants and I want to follow a total separation of concern flow.
Data from one tenant should not in any way be accessible to the other.

Example Scenario:
Say I have multiple Institutes as my clients and every institute will have all of their students onboarded on my platform. No institute should be able to access other's data.

I can think of 2 approaches:

**1. Extending ModelAdmin for Admin pages and for the APIs I can get the tenant associated to a particular user from the request.**

In this approach, I'll have to check for the tenant of a user in every modelAdmin class and get a filtered queryset in the `def get_queryset()` method

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        tenant = request.user.tenant  # using related_name of foreignkey
        queryset = Course.objects.filter(tenant_id=tenant)
```

And have to do this similarly in the `list`, `create`, `update` and `destroy` methods of the `ModelViewSet` class while creating APIs

```
class CourseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer
    permission_classes = (DjangoModelPermissions,)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tenant = request.user.tenant
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        queryset = queryset.filter(tenant__id=tenant)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

**2. Using Row Level Security provided by Postgres**

In this approach all the filtering will be done by postgres itself, but for this to work, I'll have to create a middleware that sets the (postgres) session variable, and a mechanism to enable/disable this on a model.

More about this approach can be found in the link below:

https://schinckel.net/2017/12/20/django-multitenancy-using-postgres-row-level-security/

Please suggest which approach will be better among the two above and if there's any better approach of doing this.

***Note**: It's a requirement to keep all the data of all the clients in the same DB in the same Schema.*